# Flask: how can I access the audio file captured by a user's web browser?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, openai-whisper

I am making a simple Flask webapp: users will record a conversation in the browser and receive a transcription of their conversation.

Using the Media Stream Recording [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API), users of my webapp can record their voice and hear the recording. But I want to access the file such that I can process it and return a transcript back to them. I plan to use the Whisper API for this.

I do not know how to go about 'sending' the captured audio to my Whisper model... I have tried the Fetch call but it doesn't seem to work.

My Flask app.py code is as follows:

```
import openai
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
openai.api_key = XXX

@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
if request.method == "POST":
file = request.files\["file"\]
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
model="whisper-1",
file=file,
language="en",
response_format="text",)
return render_template("index.html", result=transcript)
else:
return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

My Javascript code is as follows:

```
 // set up basic variables for app

const record = document.querySelector('.record');
const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
const soundClips = document.querySelector('.sound-clips');
const canvas = document.querySelector('.visualizer');
const mainSection = document.querySelector('.main-controls');

// disable stop button while not recording

stop.disabled = true;

//main block for doing the audio recording

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  console.log('getUserMedia supported.');

  const constraints = { audio: true };
  let chunks = [];

  let onSuccess = function(stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    visualize(stream);

    record.onclick = function() {
      mediaRecorder.start();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder started");
      record.style.background = "red";

      stop.disabled = false;
      record.disabled = true;
    }

    stop.onclick = function() {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder stopped");
      record.style.background = "";
      record.style.color = "";
      // mediaRecorder.requestData();

      stop.disabled = true;
      record.disabled = false;
    }

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
      console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

      const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip?','My unnamed clip');

      const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
      const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
      const audio = document.createElement('audio');
      const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

      clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
      audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
      deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
      deleteButton.className = 'delete';

      if(clipName === null) {
        clipLabel.textContent = 'My unnamed clip';
      } else {
        clipLabel.textContent = clipName;
      }

      clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
      clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
      clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
      soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

      audio.controls = true;
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
      chunks = [];
      const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      audio.src = audioURL;
      console.log("recorder stopped");

      deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
        e.target.closest(".clip").remove();
      }

      clipLabel.onclick = function() {
        const existingName = clipLabel.textContent;
        const newClipName = prompt('Enter a new name for your sound clip?');
        if(newClipName === null) {
          clipLabel.textContent = existingName;
        } else {
          clipLabel.textContent = newClipName;
        }
      }

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('audio', blob, clipName); // Append the blob to the form data

      // Send the form data to the server using fetch
      fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Audio file uploaded successfully');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error uploading audio file:', error);
      });

    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  }

  let onError = function(err) {
    console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);

} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}
```